# bootstrap data loading text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a twitter bootstrap button that changes to 'Loading...' when selected until the javascript loads. However I cannot get it to work...

Here is my html:

```
<button type="submit" id="sign-up" data-loading-text="Processing..." class="btn btn-sign-up">SIGN UP</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#sign-up').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    $.ajax(...).always(function () {
    btn.button('reset');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Given that this is an almost exact copy of the [Bootstrap example code](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), I'd say you're simply missing a resource (like jQuery or the Bootstrap JS file) or you've literally got `$.ajax(...)`. What does your error console say?

Comment: unexpected token which is to be expected. i am just trying to figure out what needs to be done to make this javascript element functional

Comment: Try to change button type="submit" to type="button".... I think

Comment: I don'u know if you ever solved this. If not you probly gave up by now but I am almost sure you need to add your quotes, it worked for me when it wasn't working(ie  `$.ajax('...').always`).

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution to this.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons), this feature was deprecated in v3.3.5 and removed in v4.

Comment: Drop-in solution for BS4 from a similar question [Show Loading.. using jquery in bootstrap 4 with data-loading-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240011/show-loading-using-jquery-in-bootstrap-4-with-data-loading-text/#answer-53009288)

Answer (score 4):

As you're using jQuery and bootstrap, you can follow this example on http://jsfiddle.net/liuyl/RdpRw/1/

```
$('button[data-loading-text]')
.on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    setTimeout(function () {
        btn.button('reset')
    }, 3000)
});
```

OBS: see the full sample on the link.
Notice the external libraries on the left menu on jsfiddle, you can't forget to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already solved your problem. You should place you script inside $(document).ready() callback so that the $("#sign-up") is available when the click event is registered

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sign-up').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.button('loading');
        $.ajax(...).always(function () {
            btn.button('reset');
        });
    });
});
```

Let's try the updated code here
http://jsbin.com/pamujimise/edit?html,output