# Show Loading.. using jquery in bootstrap 4 with data-loading-text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve a loading effect for a button, as demonstrated in [codepen](https://codepen.io/jmalatia/pen/HkmaA).

I am using `bootstrap 4` (beta 2) `Jquery 3.2.1`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Group View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../css/bootstrap.css" >
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit Order</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').data('loading-text', 'loading...');
      $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.button('loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $this.button('reset');
        }, 8000);
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not display "loading..." when the button is clicked.

Comment: It must be the paths for either jQuert or BS. Check your browser console,

Comment: @AdamAzad my script src is wrong?

Comment: The browser console will tell you; the code you posted is fine, so check the console for loading error.

Comment: @AdamAzad, there is no error in the console. The CSS and JS are loading fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm not sure the `.button()` method in Bootstrap v4 has the options you are trying to use. The Codepen you link to uses Bootstrap v3.

Here is how you could replicate the same behavior with Bootstrap 4.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var loadingText = '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> loading...';
    if ($(this).html() !== loadingText) {
      $this.data('original-text', $(this).html());
      $this.html(loadingText);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.html($this.data('original-text'));
    }, 2000);
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit Order</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you *please* also add `font awesome 5` to your code

Comment: Done. All you have to do is include the stylesheet and add the desired icon to the loading text.

Comment: This doesn't disable the button from being clicked again while in the loading state. I realize the question didn't specify that behavior.

Comment: You should put any action you want to execute on click in the `if ($(this).html() !== loadingText) {` condition. Of course we could also use `off()` and re-enable the handler later if we really want to deactivate the click itself. I could add a second example, if you're interested let me know.

Comment: This was not suitable for my needs since a timed state change leaved the button disabled take too long or enables too quickly (eg: AJAX requests, where I tend to use `button('loading')`). Drop-in replacement provided in my answer. works using the same markup as BS3.

Comment: to also disable the button add $this.prop("disabled", true);

Answer (score 12):

This feature is deprecated since v3.3.5 and has been removed in v4. [Source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons-stateful)

Comment: This is also mentioned in the "Migration to v4" article.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#buttons

Answer (score 10):

Ran into this same issue a few days ago and nobody seems to have a solution. So here's my jQuery plugin that seems to provide the same behavior in Boostrap 4.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.__bs4_btn = $.fn.button;
    $.fn.button = function(action) {
        if (action === 'loading' && this.data('loading-text')) {
            this.data('original-text', this.html()).html(this.data('loading-text')).prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if (action === 'reset' && this.data('original-text')) {
            this.html(this.data('original-text')).prop('disabled', false);
        }
        return this.__bs4_btn(action);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

More details: [How to Continue Using Buttons with “data-loading-text” in Bootstrap 4 with jQuery](http://www.robertmullaney.com/2018/10/25/continue-using-data-loading-text-buttons-bootstrap-4-jquery/) (my blog)

Comment: This seems to be broken in Safari + Chorme. Works in IE11 and Firefox - but on Chrome it doesnt submit the form.

Comment: Hard to diagnose your issue without a code sample. This was developed using Chrome so...

Comment: This will break the built in functions `$().button('toggle')` and `$().button('dispose')`. It is better to use a different plugin name like `$.fn.buttonState`.

Comment: I don't use those methods so they were not tested (would not imagine a "loading" button needs them). Good point if that is the case 

Comment: This could be a good solution and it was something that I was tempted to try. However I agree with Bassem, this does override the other button methods documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/buttons/#methods. It is not related to "loading" buttons but if someone uses your code, it would break the `toggle` methods if they used that method somewhere else. I think your answer would be a lot better if you could check the `action` argument and call the built-in `button` function if it was not `loading` or `reset`.

Comment: @Bassem I know it's late, but I have suggested a fix for this. Keeping all of the bootstrap predefined functionality while extending it with the loading feature, which op provided. Basically you duplicate the function and then call the function you duplicated  after the two if statements.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem and tried the example uploaded by Mavelo above however it didn't work on the queries like this:

`$('button').button('reset')`

which operates on multiple objects. Here's a modified code that supports both single and multiple button queries:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.button = function(action) {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            this.each(function(){
                if (action === 'loading' && $(this).data('loading-text')) {
                    $(this).data('original-text', $(this).html()).html($(this).data('loading-text')).prop('disabled', true);
                } else if (action === 'reset' && $(this).data('original-text')) {
                    $(this).html($(this).data('original-text')).prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```